# Why is this  Egyptian hieroglyph associated with the Hebrew letter ז [Zayin] and not the word וָו [VaV]?

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, hebrew, egyptian

**Why is this  Egyptian Hieroglyph associated with the Hebrew letter ז [Zayin] and not the word וו [VaV]?**

- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleo-Hebrew_alphabet] claims the  pictogram is the origin for the Paleo-Hebrew  zayin.
- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Egyptian_hieroglyphs] then claims the  was engraved "as a replacement for signs perceived to be dangerous to be actually written".
- We find the Hebrew word **וָו** [VaV] "hook" in [Exodus 38:28](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9899/jewish/Chapter-38.htm) which shares closer pictographic similarities to the Egyptian

**Thanks for any insight in regards to this  hieroglyph.**

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never seen Z4 (the dual strokes) used to replace a dangerous sign; single slashes, X's, and dots are more common in my experience.

Comment: @Draconis - Thank you. | Do you know the Egyptian name of the  engraving?

Comment: More relevantly, though, why are you comparing Aramaic square writing to Egyptian, rather than its ancestors? If you're linking to the wikipedia page for Paleo-Hebrew script, you've presumably looked at the tables there and seen that Paleo-Hebrew waw didn't look like a single vertical line.

Comment: To answer your other question, as far as I know, the Egyptians didn't have names for most hieroglyphic signs. Modern Egyptologists call it either "Z4" or "the dual strokes", since it looks like a pair of strokes and is used to write dual nouns (nouns indicating exactly two of something).

Comment: @Draconis - Since k'tav ashuri & k'tav ivri are debated as the original script, my hope was to learn more details regarding the  engraving (name, meaning).

Comment: All that said, I have no idea why scholars (according to Wikipedia) say zayin came from that sign either. I'm not by any means an expert on Proto-Sinaitic, but that sign in Egyptian doesn't really have anything to do with a weapon. There are other signs that would be much more obvious choices for representing "weapon". The Wikipedia page for Proto-Sinaitic suggests instead sign N34, a metal ingot, and that makes much more sense to me.

Comment: You are comparing the letter zayin with the _name_ of the letter vav. Also, for the word vav=hook it is not excluded that this meaning was adapted because of the resemblance of the hook to the letter and not vice versa, see e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/27564173

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You're comparing glyphs from very different time periods.

The word *wāw* (or *vāv*) looks like two vertical lines in the square script (ktav ashuri). However, scholars have a pretty good idea where this script came from, historically: it was adapted from the imperial Aramaic script, which came from the Phoenician script, which probably came from Proto-Sinaitic script, which was probably adapted from some form of Egyptian writing (cursive hieroglyphic or hieratic).

In other words, the square script wasn't adapted from Egyptian—the Proto-Sinaitic script was. (Probably. It's not entirely understood, mostly due to lack of evidence.) And the Proto-Sinaitic ancestor of waw wasn't a vertical line.

Besides, from the perspective of the people adapting Proto-Sinaitic, there's no real reason why hieroglyph Z4 (the two diagonal strokes) would be used to write the letter *w*. In hieroglyphic writing, that sign represents *y* (probably `/j/`), when used as the dual ending for nouns. And while Hebrew has some remnants of a dual, there's no *w* in it.